# Cannot setup a mock on a Data Provider

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, mocking

So, I am trying to test a service by setting up a mock of one the data providers it uses.
I set up my service and initialize it with an instance on the Mock.Object of my data provider. In my test case I setup the behaviour of the data provider, but when I run the test the service uses the default data provider to call the target method on.

```
public partial class RemoveContactFromContractTests
{
    private ContractsController _contractsController;
    private Mock<IContractService> _contractsServiceMock;
    private Mock<IContractsDataProvider> _contractsDataProviderMock;
    private ContractsDataProvider _contractsDataProviderMockWithContext;
    private Mock<IContactsDataProvider> _contactsDataProviderMock;
    private Mock<ILocaleDataProvider> _localeDataProviderMock;
    private Mock<ICurrentUserService> _currentUserMock;

    private ContractsService _contractsService;

    private ContractContextTest _contextTest;
    private ContractsContext _contextMock;
    private IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly int userId = 0;
    public RemoveContactFromContractTests()
    {
        _contractsServiceMock = new Mock<IContractService>();
        _currentUserMock = new Mock<ICurrentUserService>();
        _contractsDataProviderMock = new Mock<IContractsDataProvider>();
        _localeDataProviderMock = new Mock<ILocaleDataProvider>();
        _contactsDataProviderMock = new Mock<IContactsDataProvider>();
        _contractsController = new ContractsController(_contractsServiceMock.Object, _currentUserMock.Object);
        
        _contractsService = new ContractsService(_contractsDataProviderMock.Object, _localeDataProviderMock.Object, _contactsDataProviderMock.Object);

        _mapper = Mock.Mocks.AutoMapper;
        _contextTest = new ContractContextTest();
        Mock.Mocks.Init();
        _contextMock = Mock.Mocks.ContractsContext;
        _contractsDataProviderMockWithContext = new ContractsDataProvider(_contextMock, _mapper);
    }

    [Theory]
    [Trait("Contracts", "RemoveContactFromContract")]
    [MemberData(nameof(RemoveContact_From_Contract_8_ValidData_CheckDataProvider_Test_TestCaseParams))]
    public async Task RemoveContact_From_Contract_8_ValidData_CheckDataProvider_Test(Dictionary<string, object> request, Contract expectedResult)
    {
        var testContract = new Contract()
        {
            ProjectId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            ContractId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            ContactId = Guid.NewGuid(),
            Name = "testName",
            Description = "testDescription",
            EffectiveDate = DateTime.Now,
            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5),
            SignDate = DateTime.Now,
            IsActive = true
        };

        var removeContactRequest = new RemoveContactFromContractRequest() { 
            ContactId = testContract.ContactId??Guid.NewGuid(),
            ContractId = (Guid)testContract.ContractId,
            ProjectId = (Guid)testContract.ProjectId 
        };

        _contactsDataProviderMock.Setup(x => x.CheckExistingContact(contactId,projectId))
            .ReturnsAsync(true);

        var result = _contractsService.RemoveContactFromContract(removeContactRequest,0);
    }
```